# Search for Individuals with Employee Relationship for Organisations with Certain Criteria

Tags: search, relationships, smartgroups

We have a custom organisation option field showing the "Membership Type". I want to do a search (create a smartgroup) to find all individuals with a relationship "Employee of" for organisations that have specific membership types. So for example, I wish to find all employees of organisations with a membership type of "Current". Can anyone show me how I can achieve this? I do not want to use Drupal views.

Comment: `custom organisation option field showing the "Membership Type ` - is this a custom field?

Comment: Yes, this is a custom field for organisations. It does appear on the Advanced Search screen. We are not using the CiviMail component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using existing search forms.

1. Search >> Advance Search
   [image]
2. Search >> Search Builder
   [image]
3. Other option would be to create a smart group having organization contact with specific membership type and then use advance search to search employee of with target contacts in group.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Hi Pradeep, thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately our Current Employer field is not populated with any data so I need to use the "employee of" relationship, so I can't use your second option. Your first option will not restrict the individuals found to just the organisations with a specific membership type but will show all employees.

Comment: Other option would be to create a smart group having organization contact with specific membership type and then use advance search to search employee of with target contacts in group.

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't know about the Target Contacts in Group. That has solved it. Do you want to add it as an answer for me to confirm? Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Ben, I updated my answer.